# Responsive design landscape issues

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

Im working with responsive design landscape for a website, but everytime the website refresh or when you click on the menu, the css for it doesnt apply. Only on the first page when you first enter it. Im using wordpress and a theme named pinboard

The website: [www.retorikgruppen.se](http://www.retorikgruppen.se)

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 1120px) {

    .threefourthcol { width: 100%;  } 
    .threefourthcol .threecol { width: 100%; }  
    .fourcol, .onecol .fourcol { width: 100%; }  
    #wrapper {  max-width:100%; }   
    #slider .entry-container { top:28%; }   
    .threefourthcol .threecol .entry, .onecol .fourcol .entry, .fourcol .widget { margin: 5%; } 
    img.attachment-gallery-thumb {  max-width:82px; }   
    .twocol img.attachment-gallery-thumb {  max-width:74px; } 
    .single img.attachment-gallery-thumb {  max-width:100%; } 
    format-audio object { min-height:24px; }    
    .single .format-audio object { height:24px; } 
    .social-bookmarks iframe {  min-height:0; }     
    #sidebar-header {   width:468px; height:60px; margin-top:20px;  }  

}
```

Comment: Ran the site in Chrome and Firefox. I don't see any issues. Can you describe your problem further.

Comment: Im sorry, I meant when you use your phone, the CSS rules doesnt work when you refresh the page or click in the menu, on your phone

Answer (score 0):

Try meta tag "viewport". Refer [this link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/). I was also facing same issue.

Comment: Wordpress have taking care of it already: <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">, but doesnt work

Comment: Yes. I know. Try to modify it as per your need and see the changes. I had same issue while viewing site on iphone. I modified this, & it worked.

Comment: How do I modify it? Cant find it in the css

Comment: Look for changing the value of initial-scale. I had changed that. I don't have the actual code right now. Or try removing that attribute.